# Laravel / Eloquent / Counting several entries at once in the same query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I was wondering if there was a way to perform `count` several times inside the same query for multiple rows with different conditions?
For example, I'd like to `count` the number of entries which are larger than the set values for certain `IDs`. Let's say that I have this array:

```
$data= [
    0 => [
        "id" => 1,
        "points" => 25.33
    ],
    1 => [
        "id" => 55,
        "points" => 83.11
    ],
    2 => [
        "id" => 854,
        "points" => 6.05
    ]
]
```

I'd like to make a query which counts the number of entries in the DB where those entries have MORE points than the `IDs` I'm using in the array above. I can do multiple queries easily, but I was wondering if there was a way to pack it all into a single query which would give me the same result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question right.

but I think You can Use This

```
$query->whereRaw('id >  points')->get();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).